# Почему Rider не подсвечивает C# код?

Tags: c#, компиляция, rider

Клонировал проект с репозитория и почему-то C# код не подсвечивается (не выделяются классы, не показываются ошибки и т.д.). В файлах с реактом, html и css все подсвечивается нормально.
Недавно еще переустанавливал винду, могло ли удалиться что-то, что фиксило это раньше (раньше такого не было)?

[image]

**UPD1:**
Проект большой и запускается с помощью команды `dotnet run`. Может Rider не видит солюшн?

Вот структура проекта

[image]

**UPD2:**
Еще увидел в верхнем правом углу кнопку "OFF". Она видимо тоже отвечает за подсветку синтаксиса. Я ее включил и Rider стал подсвечивать очень много ошибок. Например, в самом начале, в строке `using System.Text.Json.Serialization;` `System` подсвечивается как ошибка и пишет `Cannot resolve symbol 'System'`.

**UPD3:**
В настройках `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspection Settings` почти все галочки на подсветку синтаксиса стоят.

Comment: это просто подсказка, на которую можно нажать и rider покажет il код метода/класса и т.д., это не означает, что rider c# как il, а если у вас не показывает ошибка, то скорее всего это связано с чем-то ещё

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно открыть проект через файл `.sln`, чтобы Rider получил всю информацию о проекте.

Ошибка `Cannot resolve symbol 'System'` возникла из-за того, что Rider не понял, какая версия .NET используется в этом проекте.

Comment: Да, открыл .sln и все стало подсвечиваться, спасибо